# Excel - стандартное отклонение "если"

Tags: excel, статистика

Как сделать такую задачу? Есть таблица в Excel, упрощая предельно - есть столбец А с номерами выборок, есть столбец B со значениями. Посчитать среднее по всей выборке просто - типа

```
=СРЗНАЧ(B2:B25)
```

Просто и стандартное отклонение -

```
=СТАНДОТКЛОН.Г(B2:B25)
```

По группам посчитать среднее тоже не так тяжело - в отдельную ячейку (например, X1) номер группы, и типа

```
=СРЗНАЧЕСЛИМН(B2:B25;A2:A25;X1)
```

А как посчитать для каждой группы отклонение? Только таблица широкая, столбцов много, а группы строк могут меняться - так что я не хочу указывать явно диапазоны групп. Лучше в отдельной ячейке номер, на который можно сослаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `ДСТАНДОТКЛП`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только ваши значения должны быть подписаны, и условие добавить

Comment: Да, о базе данных я как-то даже не подумал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно усложнять вычисления. Для определения среднего по группе достаточно `СРЗНАЧЕСЛИ`:

```
=СРЗНАЧЕСЛИ(A2:A25;X1;B2:B25)
```

Функции баз данных тяжелы в вычислениях (для пары формул это некритично) и требуют допонительных полей. Можно без них.

```
=СТАНДОТКЛОН.Г(ЕСЛИ(A2:A25;X1;B2:B25))
```

Формула массива, вводится сочетанием трех клавиш - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (после завершения ввода формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками)

Comment: Стало интересно сравнить скорость, сделал макрос в цикле 100 раз пересчитывать активный лист и выводить время, заполнил лист 1048575 строк случайными данными (преобразовав их потом в обычные числа, без формул). В общем время работы по формуле ДСТАНДОТКЛП - 3,79 секунды, по массиву - 13,42 секунды в 3,5 раза дольше. Но в Вашем варианте удобнее, можно например посчитать отклонения сразу по нескольким выборкам, т.е. список выборок и напротив отклонение, в моем варианте так наверно не сделаешь

Comment: По скорости - да, не уточнил: формулы массива тоже не самые скоростные (работают шустрее, если вводить не в отдельные ячейки, но массивом в диапазон). Еще многое зависит от обрабатываемых данных и типов обработки. Да и вообще - на больших массивах лучше не грузить книги формулами, обрабатывать в VBA